# Phalcon PHP can't get $_GET variable

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm a beginner with Phalcon and I just can't figure out what's happening. I'm working with OAuth2.0 and I'd like to get the authorization code from the query parameter.

As stated in the documentation, I have to use `$request->getQuery()`.The thing is, it gives me something completely different.

The URI is like this:

```
https://my.site/controller/method?foo=bar
```

Using `var_dump($request->getQuery());` returns the following:

```
array(1) { ["_url"]=> string(12) "/controller/method" }
```

This seems like the URL part in the Apache .htaccess RewriteRule that is shown in the Phalcon examples. (`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 [P,L]` (I changed the flags only))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `$request->get("foo");` work?

Comment: You can add the [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to the `RewriteRule` to retain query strings.

Comment: Showdev, thanks, it was the solution. make an answer and I will accept it.
----
Cypher, thanks for your comment, already tried that and did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to the `RewriteRule` to retain query strings.

From the docs:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```